# Why is font extension working only for PDF but not for other formats (HTML, XLS, DOC)?

Tags: html, fonts, jasper-reports, export-to-excel, export-to-word

Through Jaspersoft Studio we exported the built-in Windows Calibri font variants for use in a webapp into a font extension JAR, using the following settings:

[image: Font Settings]

The directory structure within the exported jrfontextensions.jar is as follows:

```
--jrfontextensions
  --jasperreports_extension.properties
  --fonts
    --fontsfamily1505796949749.xml
    --Custom_Font
      --calibri.ttf
      --calibrib.ttf
      --calibrii.ttf
      --calibriz.ttf
```

Contents of jasperreports_extension.properties:

```
net.sf.jasperreports.extension.registry.factory.fonts=net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fonts.SimpleFontExtensionsRegistryFactory
net.sf.jasperreports.extension.simple.font.families.ireportfamily1505796949749=fonts/fontsfamily1505796949749.xml
```

Contents of fontsfamily1505796949749.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<fontFamilies>
    <fontFamily name="Custom-Font">
        <normal><![CDATA[fonts/Custom_Font/calibri.ttf]]></normal>
        <bold><![CDATA[fonts/Custom_Font/calibrib.ttf]]></bold>
        <italic><![CDATA[fonts/Custom_Font/calibrii.ttf]]></italic>
        <boldItalic><![CDATA[fonts/Custom_Font/calibriz.ttf]]></boldItalic>
        <pdfEncoding><![CDATA[Identity-H]]></pdfEncoding>
        <pdfEmbedded><![CDATA[true]]></pdfEmbedded>
        <exportFonts>
            <export key="html"><![CDATA[Custom-Font]]></export>
            <export key="rtf"><![CDATA[Custom-Font]]></export>
            <export key="xhtml"><![CDATA[Custom-Font]]></export>
        </exportFonts>
    </fontFamily>
</fontFamilies>
```

Now when we export this report as PDF, the Calibri font embedded into the PDF as the Custom-Font displays correctly, as expected.

But we ran into problems when trying to export the report to other formats like HTML, DOC, and XLS. It seems the web browser or office apps don't recognize the "Custom-Font" and falls back to one of their default fonts: the XLS report defaults to DejaVu Sans, while the HTML, and DOC reports default to Times New Roman. The outputs in PDF, XLS, DOC, and HTML respectively are as follows:

[image: Document output]

I feel like we must be missing something obvious here - perhaps we're lacking some obscure JRExporter configuration?

Comment: Remove the HTML export font mapping if you want the HTML export to use the font file from the extension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Some background

Fonts normally exists outside of the document (installed on pc) and not all document types will allow you to embed (include) font in the document itself. Related to your document types this is the possibility to embed fonts into the document.

- **PDF**, yes you can embed the font
- **HTML**, font can not be directly embedded but jasper-report will create
  a css that contains `@font-face` with url, hence if broswer supports
  it, font will be downloaded
- **Office** (xls,xlsx,doc,docx,ppt), to embed font in [apache-poi](/questions/tagged/apache-poi)
  (library used by jasper report) is probably
  [possibile](http://apache-poi.1045710.n5.nabble.com/Font-embedding-into-XSLF-td5713937.html)
  but AFIK (99% sure) jasper-reports have not developed code to try and
  use this, since not directly supported by the library.

## What should I do now

You are misunderstanding the font-mapping interface

> Specify **replacement** fonts to use ... when **not available**

In this interface you should not put the name of your font, the font name, font-family you indicate will be used when your font is **not available**, you need to specify other standard default fonts that should be used if your font is not found.

Another good design rule (not well-documented) is to **use as "Family name"** (when you configure the font family) the **exact name of font** (if installed), hence if the computer has the font installed it will be found, since your name will map the name installed. In your case it looks like that you should replace "Custom-Font" with "Calibri"

**Why is my html not working?**, as indicated in [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46448242/why-is-font-extension-working-only-for-pdf-but-not-for-other-formats-html-xls/46463316#comment79881902_46448242) by [dada67](https://stackoverflow.com/users/983559/dada67) you should not use font-mapping for html if you like to use custom font (the mapping will redirect to mapped font), then search for the css, using code like

```
JasperReport report = JasperCompileManager.compileReport("jasper/FontExportTest.jrxml");
JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, new HashMap<String, Object>(), new JREmptyDataSource());
        
HtmlExporter exporter = new HtmlExporter();
exporter.setExporterInput(new SimpleExporterInput(jasperPrint));
exporter.setExporterOutput(new SimpleHtmlExporterOutput(new File("myHtml.html")));
SimpleHtmlExporterConfiguration configuration = new SimpleHtmlExporterConfiguration();
exporter.setConfiguration(configuration);
exporter.exportReport();
```

JasperReport will create both the file `myHtml.html` but also a folder with the name `myHtml_htmlfiles`, in this folder the css should be present, together with your `.ttf` font. If you deploy it on server naturally you need to deploy both.

Comment: Thank you guys for the replies! Our team's been stuck on this issue for weeks now, so any information that would light our way towards a solution is deeply appreciated.

So the way I understand it, is that custom fonts packaged in font extension JARs were meant primarily for use in PDFs? That's been a nagging suspicion of mine ever since I started dealing with font extensions, because most online guides I've seen to date had a heavy emphasis on rendering fonts in PDFs, but I've never read anything that would confirm it.

Comment: We've actually tried naming the custom font simply as "Calibri" at first but that approach raised some concerns after we found out that we were to deploy our webapp on our client's Linux servers, which do not come with the Calibri font built-in. Does that mean we need to install the font there prior to deployment?

Comment: Also I hadn't known that the HtmlExporter exports a file folder alongside the HTML, because our HTML report implementation consisted of passing the plain HTML string generated by the HtmlExporter to be displayed as a "browser preview" (though I admit exporting as PDF to put in iframes would have been cleaner and makes more sense now that I think about it)

Comment: @js160096 Yes font extensions were primary developed for pdf (itext) but the idea is to have a way to embed font when document type supports it. If you like your office document (doc, xls, xlsx, ppt ecc) to have a specific font you need to install font on the **client** machine (machine viewing the document, server is not enough if downloaded by other client). This is why font-mapping is used to fallback on standard similar font if not available.

Comment: *Simplifying the only secure way to give a correctly (as you expect) rendered document to a client, is to export to pdf all other formats (excluding jasper-print) may have these kind of issues or other issue related to client environment and your document structure/content*

Comment: This may seem like a limitation, but maybe the user of excel is more interested in having the data, then you deciding the font he has to view it with ;), hence consider it as a feature!