# What is meaning of exportFonts in config JasperReport font?

Tags: jasper-reports

I mimic configuration embed fonts for JasperReport (version 6.20.0)

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<fontFamilies>
    <fontFamily name="Arial">
        <normal><![CDATA[fonts/Arial/ARIAL.ttf]]></normal>
        <bold><![CDATA[fonts/Arial/ARIALB.ttf]]></bold>
        <italic><![CDATA[fonts/Arial/ARIALI.ttf]]></italic>
        <boldItalic><![CDATA[fonts/Arial/ARIALBD.ttf]]></boldItalic>
        <pdfEncoding><![CDATA[Identity-H]]></pdfEncoding>
        <pdfEmbedded><![CDATA[true]]></pdfEmbedded>
        <exportFonts/>
    </fontFamily>

    <fontFamily name="TimesNewRoman">
        <normal><![CDATA[fonts/TimesNewRoman/TIMES.ttf]]></normal>
        <bold><![CDATA[fonts/TimesNewRoman/TIMESB.ttf]]></bold>
        <italic><![CDATA[fonts/TimesNewRoman/TIMESI.ttf]]></italic>
        <boldItalic><![CDATA[fonts/TimesNewRoman/TIMESBI.ttf]]></boldItalic>
        <pdfEncoding><![CDATA[Identity-H]]></pdfEncoding>
        <pdfEmbedded><![CDATA[true]]></pdfEmbedded>
        <exportFonts/>
    </fontFamily>

    <fontFamily name="DejaVu Serif">
        <normal>net/sf/jasperreports/fonts/dejavu/DejaVuSerif.ttf</normal>
        <bold>net/sf/jasperreports/fonts/dejavu/DejaVuSerif-Bold.ttf</bold>
        <italic>net/sf/jasperreports/fonts/dejavu/DejaVuSerif-Italic.ttf</italic>
        <boldItalic>net/sf/jasperreports/fonts/dejavu/DejaVuSerif-BoldItalic.ttf</boldItalic>
        <pdfEncoding>Identity-H</pdfEncoding>
        <pdfEmbedded>true</pdfEmbedded>
        <exportFonts>
            <export key="net.sf.jasperreports.html">'DejaVu Serif', 'Times New Roman', Times, serif</export>
        </exportFonts>
    </fontFamily>

</fontFamilies>
```

What is meaning and benefit of this code snippet

```xml
        <exportFonts>
            <export key="net.sf.jasperreports.html">'DejaVu Serif', 'Times New Roman', Times, serif</export>
        </exportFonts>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

> It specifies the replacement fonts to use if the font-family is not available on the target environment.

<sup>Description from TICO JasperSoft Studio during font-extension creation</sup>

To understand this, you should know that font-extension was primarily added to export to pdf, embed the desired fonts in the pdf.

However jasper report can export to many different formats and in your case:

```
<export key="net.sf.jasperreports.html">'DejaVu Serif', 'Times New Roman', Times, serif</export>
```

or

```
<export key="html">'DejaVu Serif', 'Times New Roman', Times, serif</export>
```

Is stating that when **exporting to html** (and only html) it should generate css similar to

```
body {
  font-family: 'DejaVu Serif', 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
}
```

Which indicate sequenze of font to use if one is not available on user platform (search for css font-family attribute to learn more).

The only use for this tag that I know of is if you wish to export to html or rtf and for html only **add** if you like the substitution, if instead you like to use custom font do **not** added it, jasper report will generate css to include the font (font-face tag). See my "old" [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46463316/5292302) for more information about font-extension limitations.